# Mouse press capture on QGraphicsView's scene

Tags: c++, qt

I have this:

**mapdialog2.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class MapDialog2;
}

class MapDialog2 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MapDialog2(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MapDialog2();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event);
    void reject();
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event);

private:
    Ui::MapDialog2 *ui;

    QGraphicsScene *scene;

};
```

and this:

**mapdialog2.cpp**

```
MapDialog2::MapDialog2(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MapDialog2)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->addPixmap(QPixmap(":/new/image/project_images/Screenshot from 2015-03-09 15:37:24.png"));
    scene->activePanel();

    ui->graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        scene->addRect(50+i*30,100,50,100, QColor(0,200,0,100),QColor(20+i*20,0,0,100));
    }

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

}

void QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Debug Message";

    QPointF mousePos(event->buttonDownScenePos(Qt::LeftButton).x(),
                          event->buttonDownScenePos(Qt::LeftButton).y());

    qDebug() << mousePos;
}
```

I want to capture the mouse position when I press the left mouse button. But that function is never called. No presses are ever captured. Why?

The zoom and panning is all working okay, but I can't capture mouse events on the scene. I Think the problem lies with the fact that I should capture within the scene and not the `QGraphisView`, or the `QWidget` for that matter.

Comment: Use `override` keyword to prevent such error in future. There are no `void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);` method in `QDialog`. It is not clear, what you are trying to catch.

Comment: Btw, do you know, what is interhirance? You can't simple write your own `void QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)` method to override it. You need to subclass `QGraphicsScene` for it.

Comment: Typo... I mean inheritance

Comment: I'm trying to catch a mouse press event on the scene QGraphicsScene.

Comment: If you implement mousePressEvent, I suggest also implementing mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. In addition, call event->accept() at the end of those functions: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#accept or call the base class function e.g. QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);